# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PlatformInfo' - Python - ObjectListView

Tags: python-3.x, module, wxpython, objectlistview, objectlistview-python

I know this is most likely a very common question, but i am at the end of my tether trying to work it out. I have install ObjectListView-1.3.1 module for Python-3.4.3 but every time i run my code i get the following trace back and the code fails to run.

```
C:\Python34\python.exe 
C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/wxPythonPhoenixTest/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/wxPythonPhoenixTest/main.py", line 9, in <module>
from ObjectListView import ObjectListView, ColumnDefn
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\objectlistview-1.3.1-py3.4.egg\ObjectListView\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\objectlistview-1.3.1-py3.4.egg\ObjectListView\ObjectListView.py", line 107, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\objectlistview-1.3.1-py3.4.egg\ObjectListView\CellEditor.py", line 55, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PlatformInfo'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have run my code in Python-2.7 with the ObjectListView-1.2.1, and that works fine, so am assuming that there should not be a problem with it (Though this maybe a downfall).

If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it! and applogies if I have made any Stack Over flow faux pa, as i am new.

Cheers Mark

Comment: What do you get if you run this? `c:\Python34\python.exe -c "import wx; print(wx.PlatformInfo)"`

Comment: Hi Robin, thank you for getting back to me, will check this out when i get home and feed it back.

Comment: After running that line i got the following

C:\Users\Mark>c:\Python34\python.exe -c "import wx; print(wx.PlatformInfo)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PlatformInfo'

Comment: You likely have a module or package on your `sys.path` that is named "wx" but is not wxPython.

Comment: Hi Robin, apologies for taking so long to reply. I have installed wxpython from again from pycharm and that has appeared to resolved it. Thank you for your help!